# CartoDB - Update column from local csv

Tags: carto

So I uploaded a csv from my local drive and set up the map, but I would like to update a column of data every day and re-upload the csv, but keep map settings.

The dataset is very simple: one column for country names and one with values.  Only the values change every day, not the country names

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different approaches here:

- Using Sync tables with your local file being synchronized from a Dropbox/GDrive folder. Countries will be automatically georeferenced each time.
- Using an automatic script in your end that updates your table with the new information via the SQL API: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can sync your data with Google Drive or Dropbox. [Here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/excel_data_sync.html) is a tutorial about it.

For doing that, you need a [John Snow](http://cartodb.com/pricing-features) account (at least).